# Shell script to function on subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cd-command

I want to write a simple shell script that will go into all the sub-folders in a directory, and organise the files in the sub-folders into new directories. Basically in terminal it would look like:

```
cd ../subfolder1
mkdir newfolder
mv *.txt newfolder
cd ../subfolder2
mkdir newfolder
mv *.txt newfolder
etc.
```

However, the `cd` command doesn't seem to work for the shell script. 
Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Please explain - why do you say that `cd` doesn't work for shell scripts? Of course it does...

Comment: @bobleponge314 `cd` works in shell scripts, it just doesn't change the directory *outside* of the shell script.

Answer (score 2):

If your directory structure is as follow:

```
├── subfolder1
│   ├── foo.txt
│   └── bar.other
└── subfolder2
    ├── foo2.txt
    └── baz.old
```

Running the following command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type d -exec sh -c "mkdir {}/newfolder && mv {}/*.txt {}/newfolder" \;
```

Will create the below tree structure:

```
├── subfolder1
│   ├── newfolder
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   ├── bar.other
└── subfolder2
    ├── newfolder
    │   └── foo2.txt
    ├── baz.old
```